# Bulk Inserts/Updates Are Slow Using On Conflict with JSONB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm doing a bulk insert from a giant csv file that needs to turn into a both a relational and JSONB object at the same time into a table. Problem: the inserts need to do ether an insert or update. If it's an update. The column needs to append the JSON object to the row. The current setup I have has individual INSERT/UPDATE calls and of course, it's horribly slow.

Example Import Command I'm Running:

```sql
INSERT INTO "trade" ("id_asset", "trade_data", "year", "month") VALUES ('1925ad09-51e9-4de4-a506-9bccb7361297', '{"28":{"open":2.89,"high":2.89,"low":2.89,"close":2.89}}', 2017, 3)  ON CONFLICT ("year", "month", "id_asset") DO
UPDATE SET "trade_data" = "trade"."trade_data" || '{"28":{"open":2.89,"high":2.89,"low":2.89,"close":2.89}}' WHERE "trade"."id_asset" = '1925ad09-51e9-4de4-a506-9bccb7361297' AND "trade"."year" = 2017 AND "trade"."month" = 3;
```

I've tried wrapping my script in a `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`, but it didn't improve performance at all and I tried a few configurations, but it didn't seem to help.

```sql
\set autocommit off;
set schema 'market';
\set fsync off;
\set full_page_writes off;
SET synchronous_commit TO off;
\i prices.sql
```

This whole thing is extremely slow, and I'm not sure how to re-write the query without loading a ton of data into RAM using my program just to spit out a large INSERT/UPDATE command efficiently for Postgres to read. Since related data could be a million rows or another file all together to properly generate a JSON w/ out losing current JSON data that's already in the database.

Comment: It does 2-5 inserts per second, mind that this is a million lines of insert/updates. I even tried re-indexing the table, but it doesn't do much. Not sure if something changed in Postgres 11, that makes those configurations I posted not work or something.

Comment: how big are your json object?  Until they get ridiculously big, I get thousands of inserts per second.  JSON is no incrementally updated, so each time you append it has to rewrite the entire thing.

Comment: "\set fsync off;"  Is this psql?  that is not the syntax of changing database parameters, that just setting script variable with a confusing name.  That database parameter cannot be changed at the session level anyway.

Comment: JSON objects don't get too big. Max entries are 30. So I wouldn't assume that would be what's slowing it down. Yes, this is psql, I assume I should be doing this directly on server? -- Would I see a giant gain?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with "psql", it is just that `\set` in "psql" doesn't do what you think it does.  Although it is hard to see how that matters.  I don't know what to do to make it faster, as there is no reason it should be that nearly that slow in the first place.  Can you use system tool to see where the load on the system is?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just simply scp my sql file into the server and ran psql on server and set the settings I posted and now my migration is 10x faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `scp` moved my large SQL file into the Postgres server and re-ran the commands inside psql and now the migration is extremely faster.